# Получение дескрипторов всех контролов одного окна.

Tags: winapi

Хотелось бы узнать как это делается и в целом улучшить свои знания в области системного программирования. Пытался читать Джеффри Рихтера, но мне не понравилось, да и по интересующим меня темам ничего там не нашел.

Comment: [EnumChildWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633494(v=vs.85).aspx) переберет все дочерние окна заданного родительского. Только зачем?

Comment: К примеру, хочу получить текст какого-либо Edit'а или перехватить этот текст. Да не суть важно зачем, просто интересно, хочу разобраться во всем этом. А вы не могли бы привести коротенький пример применения этой функции, либо указать источники? Я читал MSDN, возникли кое-какие вопросы касательно этой функции.

Comment: >А вы не могли бы привести коротенький пример применения этой функции

 BOOL CALLBACK MyEnumChild( HWND hwndChild, LPARAM lParam ){
  TCHAR Buffer[255];
  //
  ::GetWindowText( hwndChild, Buffer, 255 );
  ::MessageBox( NULL, Buffer, TEXT(""), MB_OK );
  return TRUE;
 }
 ...
 ::EnumChildWindows( hWndParent, MyEnumChild, NULL );

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!